# Pickup estimates for future time Uber API

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to get the pickup estimate at a future time from the Uber API. I have the user's start and end locations.

For example, if I want to book a ride 6 hours from now (given the users's pickup location and drop location) I would like to know how long the cab will take to reach my pickup location 6 hours from now.

I've perused the Uber API docs completely and they don't have this feature yet. This is a completely client side app and would like some insight into approaching this problem.

** EDIT **

I know beforehand the time at which I want to reach my destination and have the travel time from the pickup location to the destination (from Goole Maps API) at that future time.

Let's assume drivers are available in the area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to achieve? This sounds like next to impossible.

Comment: BTW. Your assumptions are vague? What you mean by "drivers" (one driver or 100 of them) and by "area" (the same street, the same neighbourhood, the same town)? Those are variables that affect outcome.

Comment: By drivers I mean >=1 and available meaning available to pick up. Not a 100 miles away (obviously). Just in the vicinity. For arguments sake (and for the sake of this question) let's say within a 3 mi radius.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an impossible task given we have no way of knowing exactly from where the driver will "start" moving towards the pickup point.

Comment: Most naive implementation is to poll their API at a set interval. But I don't want to do that. Was looking for some answers from you nice people :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Uber works, but most taxi corporations give pickup time estimations based on number of "free" cabs around the pickup point *at the moment*. This method is most accurate, but you cannot use it for future dates, because to do that you would have to predict future positions of taxis.

You could, at least in theory, try to use probabilistic approach and give approximate estimations by querying Uber for estimations for different places at different times, and once you have enough data, predict average waiting times.

That would be, however, less accurate, and wouldn't take into account random events, for example, based on historical data average pickup time at place X at Fridays 5 P.M. may be 2 minutes, but since next Friday a major sporting event is scheduled at that place so in reality you might not be able to catch a cab at all.

Comment: Absolutely agree. But this does not need something that involved. I was wondering if maybe I was missing something. Thanks for your answers though :).